# Trying to populate two tables with a pivot between them

Tags: mysql, laravel, pivot-table

I'm trying to populate two mySQL tables connected by a pivot table between them in a Laravel controller, here's how my code looks at the moment:

```
public static function createUser($request)
{
    $user = request()->validate([
        'full_name' => 'required',
        'username' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required|alpha_num',
        'role' => 'required'
    ]);
    $user['password'] = bcrypt($user['password']);
    $user->factory_data()->attach($request->id, ['division_name' => $request->input('division'), 'work_center_name' => $request->input('center')]);
    User::create($user);
}
```

What basically this piece of code tries to achieve is this: I'm trying to validate the input of the first four fields, use bcrypt on the password, and then attach the input from the other two fields to the user in the request. I'm quite lost at how am supposed to complete this task, at this time the error i'm getting from Laravel's Telescope is `Call to a member function factory_data() on array`. Can someone help me out or point what i'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!
P.S. I'm willing to provide all the code needed for solving the issue.

Comment: You are calling factory_data on a validated request NOT on a model. change the variable name of the request or initialize $user on create

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just flip the last two lines, you can't attach to an array, must create the user first

```php
public static function createUser($request)
{
    $validatedData = request()->validate([
        'full_name' => 'required',
        'username' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required|alpha_num',
        'role' => 'required'
    ]);
    $validatedData['password'] = bcrypt($validatedData['password']);
    $user = User::create($validatedData);
    $user->factory_data()->attach($request->id, [
        'division_name' => $request->input('division'),
        'work_center_name' => $request->input('center')
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Oh, i see what i was doing wrong. Thanks for the help, Caddy!

Comment: I have to wait 15-20 minutes after i create the question in order to accept the answer, will do as soon as i can! Thanks again for editing your answer!

Comment: Thanks, I didn't edit... @N69S did so thanks to him

Comment: happy to help :)